# Selecting two columnar sums in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I can easily select the sum of one column using the `SUM()` function in MySQL like so:

```
SELECT SUM(`someColumn`) FROM `table`
```

Is it also possible to return the sum of a second column with the same query? Similar to this:

```
SELECT SUM (`someColumn`, `anotherColumn`) FROM `table`
```

Running such a query returns me the following access violation:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `anotherColumn`) FROM `table`' at line 1
```

Comment: Do you want to add together the two coloum or show them separetly?

Comment: @PeterRing Separately. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(`someColumn`, 0)+ COALESCE(`anotherColumn`, 0)) as TotalSum FROM `table`
```

or if you want these separately:

```
SELECT SUM(`someColumn`) as Sum1, SUM(`anotherColumn`) as Sum2 FROM `table`
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT SUM(`someColumn`) + SUM(`anotherColumn`) as TotalSum FROM `table`
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, (col1+col2+col3) AS Total FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum more than one column, you simply select the sum of more than one column.

If you only want the total of the columns, you can do something like:

```
SELECT SUM(col1+col2+...+coln) AS all_total
```

If you want to keep the sums separate, you can do:

```
SELECT SUM(col1) AS total1, SUM(col2) AS total2, ..., SUM(coln) AS totaln
```